# Connect Cadence to Azure Cosmo Cassandra API (Cadence workflow)

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

I am running cadence with cassandra externally running using docker run -e CASSANDRA_SEEDS=10.x.x.x e ubercadence/server:. and its running sucessfully.

Azure cosmos says, any system running on Cassandra can use Azure cosmos using provided cosmos cassandra APi, by modifying the client connection creation code, for example : GO app sample code :

func GetSession(cosmosCassandraContactPoint, cosmosCassandraPort, cosmosCassandraUser, cosmosCassandraPassword string) *gocql.Session {
clusterConfig := gocql.NewCluster(cosmosCassandraContactPoint)
port, err := strconv.Atoi(cosmosCassandraPort)

```
clusterConfig.Authenticator = gocql.PasswordAuthenticator{Username: cosmosCassandraUser, Password: cosmosCassandraPassword}
clusterConfig.Port = port
clusterConfig.SslOpts = &gocql.SslOptions{Config: &tls.Config{MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12}}
clusterConfig.ProtoVersion = 4

session, err := clusterConfig.CreateSession()
...
return session
```

}
From my end, I can connect external cassandra's cqlsh(which cadence is using for persisting) to azure cosmos and can create KeySpace, table in azure cosmo db. However, when I run Cadence server, all new tables are still created on local cassandra itself(instead of Axure cosmos) might be, cadence is connected to cassandra only.

So there are basically 2 question shared below :

1.Since cadence is written in GO, can we modify the source code to establish connection to AzureCosmoDb. or

or can we pass the cosmocassandra's host, port, username, password, while running the cassandra and cadence separately (docker run -e CASSANDRA_SEEDS=10.x.x.x e ubercadence/server:)
cosmosCassandraContactPoint : xyz.cassandra.cosmos.azure.com cosmosCassandraPort : 10350 cosmosCassandraUser : xyz cosmosCassandraPassword : xyz

Answer (score -1):

It’s really exciting that Azure Cosmo Cassandra is now support LWT!

I took a quick look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cassandra/lwt-cassandra-api)

I think it’s may not going to work directly, because it doesn’t support [LoggedBatch](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cassandra/cassandra-support)

But [Cadence is using logged batch](https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/master/common/persistence/nosql/nosqlplugin/cassandra/tasks.go#L264):

I think it’s probably okay to use unlogged batch in Cadence.
Because all the operation are in a single partition always.
From the [Datastax docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/cql/cql/cql_using/useBatch.html):

`Single partition batch operations are atomic automatically, while multiple partition batch operations require the use of a batchlog to ensure atomicity`

This means using unlogged batch should be the same for Cadence.
(though I believe Cadence choose to use logged batch for safe)

It should work if we change the code slightly in the Cadence Cassandra plugin